# Where can I find the latest release of Xj3D

Tags: java

I'm working on a java application that's going to display X3D models externally and I've done some research and I've found that Xj3D is one of the best ways of importing the X3D models in. However I'm struggling to find the correct folder to download that has all the right .jars in, and I want to know where I can find the one that has them all in as all the ones that I can find only have one or two .jars in, and I think that there are more as it says on http://www.xj3d.org/tutorials/xj3d_application.html

Can anyone help me on where I can find the right downloadable folder that has them all in, thanks :)

Comment: Still have to find a way to download it. When I go onto the http://www.web3d.org/x3d/applications/xj3d/ web page, it says the web page is not found. Still need help :)

Answer (score 0):

The current stable release is: 1.0
Released on 15 April 2006

Please refer the below link,

```
http://www.xj3d.org/

http://www.xj3d.org/snapshots.html
```

Comment: But when I go on the first one to download the Xj3D files, it directs me to the Web3D Consortium page and says that the page can not be found, I've already tried that way, and when I go to the second one, it carries on asking for authentication when I click on something to download

Comment: Anonymous svn read access can be had by using the following command:

  svn checkout http://svn.xj3d.org/xj3d_code
There is no password needed. However, this will check out all versions of Xj3D. We recommend instead, using the URL http://svn.xj3d.org/xj3d_code/trunk. We use the SVN convention of trunk and branch separate directories at the root of the tree, so you can find the various branches under xj3d_code/branches

There are separate SVN repositories for each managed codebase, including this website. You can browser these via the web by heading to http://svn.xj3d.org/.

Comment: So by going on those, I'd be able to fully download Xj3D?

Comment: Yes, and its for an SVN.

Comment: I've been on all three of the links that you've provided, and I still can't find a way on how to download it

Comment: I still haven't found a way to download it with those links that you've provided.